# How to change antd theme in Vite config?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, vite

It is a project composed of Vite & React & antd.

I want to handle antd theme dynamically in vite.config.ts.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to modify less.modifyVars value in React component.

This is the current screen.

[light state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09exc.jpg) /
[dark state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjI5o.jpg)

In dark mode, the style of the select component does not work properly.

```
import { getThemeVariables } from 'antd/dist/theme'

...

css: {
  modules: {
    localsConvention: 'camelCaseOnly'
  },
  preprocessorOptions: {
    less: {
      javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: {
          ...getThemeVariables({
            dark: true // dynamic
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while, but this is works for me now:

You need to make sure you import less on demand. I use plugin `vite-plugin-imp` to achieve. And then `getThemeVariables` should be work well.

```
import vitePluginImp from 'vite-plugin-imp';
import { getThemeVariables } from 'antd/dist/theme';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    // ...
    vitePluginImp({
      libList: [
        {
          libName: 'antd',
          style: (name) => `antd/es/${name}/style`,
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      // { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') },
      // fix less import by: @import ~
      // https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2185#issuecomment-784637827
      { find: /^~/, replacement: '' },
    ],
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        // modifyVars: { 'primary-color': '#13c2c2' },
        modifyVars: getThemeVariables({
          dark: true,
          // compact: true,
        }),
        javascriptEnabled: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Moreover: you can get more inspiration from here: [vite-react/vite.config.ts](https://github.com/theprimone/vite-react/blob/master/vite.config.ts)

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: @cigien Thanks for your reminder of the policy. Maybe it is okey now?

Comment: With the above method, it is difficult to switch between dark and light themes.

Comment: @Chad.K You want change themes on runtime? Maybe you can try this: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme-variable

Comment: I'm trying to change variables with this, and it does not work at all.

Comment: @SalahAdDin You should make sure you import antd less correctly.

Answer (score 7):

1. You need to import 'antd/dist/antd.less' instead of 'antd/dist/antd.css'
2. Install dependency for less `npm add -D less`. Vite will automatically catch it.
3. Use the following config:

```
   css: {
     preprocessorOptions:{ 
       less: {
         modifyVars: {
           'primary-color': '#1DA57A',
           'heading-color': '#f00',
         },
         javascriptEnabled: true,
       },
     },
   },
```

Comment: This works perfectly! However, in my case, I had antd 4.x, so I had to install less 3.x