# Function 'each' is undefined antd Vite with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less, antd, vite

I´m getting this error in **React** when importing some components from **antd** library.

Looks like the error is at:
`\node_modules\antd\es\input\style\status.less:7:0` (See the picture attached)

Examples of imported components that make the bug show up: Table, Input.

Examples of imported components that have no effect to cause the bug: Col, Row, Progress, Menu, Button...

I created the project using **Vite 2.8.6**

Libs installed:

`"react": "^17.0.2",`
`"less": "2.7.2",`
`"antd": "^4.19.2"`
`"vite-plugin-imp": "^2.1.6"`

I noticed that the bug started to happen after I customized the antd theme using the plugin **vite-plugin-imp** [How to change antd theme in Vite config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69039093/how-to-change-antd-theme-in-vite-config) , and adding some configuration in the **vite.config.ts** file, I´ll show it below. Before I added the custom theme configuration, it was displaying all the antd components normally (but of course, with the default theme, which I dont want to).

```js
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vitePluginImp from 'vite-plugin-imp';

export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: {
          'primary-color': '#97D700',
          'border-radius-base': '7px',
          'font-family': 'Rubik',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: /^~/, replacement: '' }],
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    vitePluginImp({
      libList: [
        {
          libName: 'antd',
          style: (name) => `antd/es/${name}/style`,
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
});
```

[image: output of the bug showed in the browser]

Comment: The [each()](https://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each) function was added in Less v3.7.0. Your version is too old

Comment: Gonna try to update it!

Comment: I installed again with version 3.7.0 and it worked! Thanks a lot Phil :)

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that my `less` dependency installed was too old `"2.7.2"`, The each() function was added in Less `v3.7.0`. So I updated it and it worked :)